# Setup WebSite MVC: Config IIS Condition

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

I need create Setup for my WebSite ASP.NET MVC Proyect and must check if IIS its installed and if not installed must do automatically.
What i do is

```
Condition: (IISMAJORVERSION >= "#5" AND IISMINORVERSION >= "#1") OR 
IISMAJORVERSION >="#6"
InstallUrl:
Message: [VSDIISMSG]
```

[SetUp says](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hth6h.png)

So, What must i do? Thanks!